# How to restrict the values read from a table based upon another table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with sqlserver and C#. I have to populate a dropdownbox with times of 30 min increment between a start and end time from a table named time_series. For example, the date read from this table will be like, 10:00 am, 10:30 am, 11:00 am, 11:30 am ... 5:00 pm. I have another two tables with start (start_time table) and end times ( end_time table) with specific values. For example if the start_time table has a value of  11:00 am then the time series should start from 11:00 am instead of 10:00 am. Similarly, if the end-time table has a value of 3:00 pm then the time series should go only up to 3:00 pm and not up to 5:00 pm. Is there any way of doing it in sql? I could do it in C# by first reading all the three tables and then restrict the time series by values for the start_time and end_time tables. However I would like to do it in sql without C#.

Thanks

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

This will create a list of 30 minutes jumps starting with the given time and ending with the given end time for the given target date:

```
DECLARE @StartTime TIME={t'08:00:00'};
DECLARE @EndTime TIME={t'17:30:00'};

DECLARE @targetDate DATETIME={d'2016-10-12'};

WITH JumpsOf30 AS
(
    SELECT TOP 48 (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))-1) * 30 AS Jump
    FROM sys.objects --you don't need more than 48, so the count of this table should suffice...
)
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,Jump,@targetDate+CAST(@StartTime AS datetime))
FROM JumpsOf30
WHERE  DATEADD(MINUTE,Jump,@targetDate+CAST(@StartTime AS datetime))<=@targetDate+CAST(@EndTime AS datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a TVF to create dynamic datetime ranges.  It is much faster than the CTE approach.

```
Select *
      ,TimeString=Format(RetVal,'hh:mm:ss tt') 
 From  [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('1900-01-01 10:00:00','1900-01-01 17:00:00','MI',30)
 Where Cast(RetVal as Time)>=cast(GetDate() as Time)
```

Returns

```
RetSeq  RetVal                     TimeString   << Current time was 3:22pm
12      1900-01-01 15:30:00.000    03:30:00 PM
13      1900-01-01 16:00:00.000    04:00:00 PM
14      1900-01-01 16:30:00.000    04:30:00 PM
15      1900-01-01 17:00:00.000    05:00:00 PM
```

The UDF of needed

```
CREAT FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Range-Date] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
*/
```